# convert cmd curl to php curl

Tags: php, curl

My curl request is

```
curl -X POST -H "user:myusername" -H "password:mypassword" "http://10.243.166.xx:xxxx/CGRequestHandler/Controller?msisdn=88016317521xx&vas_id=DFN0100001&trx_id=27859456800706&event_type=1&event_cost=2.44&product_name=beautytips&channel_code=SMS&content_id=&cp_id=DFNMEDIA&circle_id=DEL&opt1=DFNMEDIA&opt2=DFN0100001&opt3=-1&opt4=-1&opt5=-1&validity=1"
```

which working fine in Linux terminal but when i use php for same code its not working for authentication problem my php code is

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['username:myusename,password:mypassword']);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

whats wrong am i doing? please help 
Thank you.

Comment: Well, you've commented out the authentication bit, `CURLOPT_USERPWD`.

Comment: I have try commented code also but same problem

Comment: And what _exactly_ is that problem? In what way is it "not working"?  Are you getting any response returned? Have you checked the response of [curl_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)?

Comment: Yes its not curl error its receive a response "Authentication fail".

Comment: can you post the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have copied the headers incorrectly:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['username:myusename', 'password:mypassword']);
```

should be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['user:myusename', 'password:mypassword']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option is not correct. Each header is supposed to be a separate element of the array.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['username:myusename', 'password:mypassword']);
```

Comment: Not working, same response Authentication fail.

Comment: I've never before seen authentication information sent in separate `username` and `password` headers, instead of using HTTP basic authentication.

Comment: But this is definitely the PHP equivalent of the `-H` option in the terminal.